# Following code is working flawless in Mac Os X but it gives error in windows and raspberry os

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

We use the following code to process the image captured by video camera and classify it whether its a forward, left or right sign. They're all about traffic.In forward firstdetection uses a cascade.Cascade tries to find right or left arrow.Then if it does not classify it then it's a forward direction. If it returns true we call from decider deciderfunc.Everytime deciderfunc it runs slowly(again in windows and pi).  It decider whether it's left or right. Now when I run it under mac os x it works perfect. But in windows it gives the following error. I think the error is about video capture and cap read. How can I fix this issue ? Thanks in advance..:

```
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
0 31
F
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -1072873821
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/merts/Desktop/the3r4yslayer-master/combiner.py", line 15, in <module>
\gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

[ WARN:0] terminating async callback

Process finished with exit code 1
```

main:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from forward import firstdetection
from decider import deciderfunc

cameraCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cv2.namedWindow('camera')
success, frame = cameraCapture.read()
forwardcounter = leftcounter = rightcounter = total = 0

while success:
    success, frame = cameraCapture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 37)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50, param1=160, param2=40)
    cv2.imshow('camera', frame)



    try:
        if circles is not None:
            flag = firstdetection()

            if flag:
                if deciderfunc():  # it gives answer about left or right
                    print('L')
                else:
                    print('R')
            else:
                print('F')  # will be replaced according to pi

    except:
        continue
```

decider:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def deciderfunc():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    success, camera = cap.read()
    left = right = total = 0
    while success and total < 15:
        value_0 = value_1 = 0

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(camera, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 37)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50, param1=160, param2=40)
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        max_r, max_i = 0, 0
        for i in range(len(circles[:, :, 2][0])):
            if circles[:, :, 2][0][i] > 50 and circles[:, :, 2][0][i] > max_r:
                max_i = i
                max_r = circles[:, :, 2][0][i]
        x, y, r = circles[:, :, :][0][max_i]


        square = camera[y - r:y + r, x - r:x + r]
        zone_0 = square[square.shape[0] * 2 // 8:square.shape[0] * 6 // 8, square.shape[1] * 3 // 8:square.shape[1] * 4 // 8]
        gray_0 = cv2.cvtColor(zone_0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_0 = cv2.medianBlur(gray_0, 37)
        zone_1 = square[square.shape[0] * 2 // 8:square.shape[0] * 6 // 8, square.shape[1] * 4 // 8:square.shape[1] * 5 // 8]
        gray_1 = cv2.cvtColor(zone_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_1 = cv2.medianBlur(gray_1, 37)
        image_data_0 = np.asarray(img_0)

        for i in range(len(image_data_0)):
            for j in range(len(image_data_0[0])):
                value_0 = value_0 + image_data_0[i][j]
        image_data_1 = np.asarray(img_1)

        for i in range(len(image_data_1)):
            for j in range(len(image_data_1[0])):
                value_1 = value_1 + image_data_1[i][j]

        if value_0 < value_1:
            left+=1
            total+=1
        else:
            right+=1
            total+=1

    if left>right:
        return 1

    else:
        return 0
```

forward:

```
import cv2
def firstdetection():


    cameraCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)


    success, cap = cameraCapture.read()
    ok_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('new_kocum.xml')      # this is the cascade we just made. Call what you want
    flag=0
    true_counter = 0
    false_counter = 0
    while success and flag<31:

        flag+=1
        img = cap
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        oks = ok_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 3, 4)
        if len(oks)!=0:
            true_counter+=1
            continue
        else:
            false_counter+=1
            continue
    if(true_counter>false_counter):
        cameraCapture.release()
        print(true_counter,false_counter)
        return True
    else:
        cameraCapture.release()
        print(true_counter,false_counter)
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely reading from a non existent device. The `VideoCapture(1)` call instructs OoenCV to read from device number 1, but fails if there is none. Try `VideoCapture(0)` first as a webcam is most likely to show up there first (unless there's another device at 0 in which case it might be 1)